# Explicitly construct a probability space and two independent Cauchy distributed random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> **a)** Explicitly construct a measure space $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ such that $\mu(X) = 1$ and a function $f:(X, \mathscr{A}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ that is measurable and Cauchy distributed with parameter $\lambda$, i.e. $$\forall b \in \mathbb{Q}: \mu(f^{-1}((-\infty,b]) = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot \arctan \left( \frac{b}{\lambda} \right) + \frac{1}{2}. $$
>
> **b)** Explicitly construct a measure space $(Y,\mathscr{B}, \mu)$ such that $\mu(Y) = 1$ and two functions $f,g: (Y, \mathscr{B}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ measurable and Cauchy distributed with parameters $\lambda$ and $\gamma$, respectively and that are independent, i.e. the sets $$\{f^{-1}(A) \ \mid \ A \in \mathcal{B} \} \text{ and } \{g^{-1}(A) \ \mid \ A \in \mathcal{B} \} $$ are independent $\sigma$-algebras.

I have no idea how to start **a)**. For **b)**, I know that if we have two measure spaces $(X_1, \mathscr{A}_1, \mu_1)$ and $(X_2, \mathscr{A}_2, \mu_2)$, then we can construct the product-measure space $(X, \mathscr{A}_1 \otimes \mathscr{A}_2, \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)$ and the the projections from $X$ on each variable will be measurable and independent, but I don't know how to do it without **a)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)**

Take $(X,\mathscr A)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ and define measure $\mu$ by stating that its corresponding distribution is: $$F_{\lambda}(x)=\frac1{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)+\frac12$$

Then identity function $f:X=\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ is measurable and Cauchy-distributed with parameter $\lambda$.

**b)**

Take $(Y,\mathscr B)=(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2))$.

It can be proved that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2))=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\otimes\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Define $\mu$ by stating that its corresponding distribution function is:$$F(x,y)=F_{\lambda}(x)F_{\gamma}(y)$$

Then the projections $f,g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ will do the job.